# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, classcastexception

I'm using the following code to convert char[] to string, but it is throwing:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C

```
char[] charArray = user.getUserPassword();  
String userPassword = String.valueOf(charArray);
```

Here `user.getUserPassword()` returns char[]. I also tried the following:

```
String userPassword = new String(charArray);
```

But it also throws the same exception. (I'm using java 8.)

The complete stack trace;

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveCharacterArrayTypeDescriptor.unwrap(PrimitiveCharacterArrayTypeDescriptor.java:40)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:616)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1901)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at com.humworld.ccs.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl.login(UserDAOImpl.java:29)
at com.humworld.ccs.serviceimpl.UserServiceImpl.login(UserServiceImpl.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.login(Unknown Source)
at com.humworld.ccs.controller.LoginController.loginAuthentication(LoginController.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the UserDAOImpl class;

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Object[]> login(String UserName, String UserPassword) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = HqlConstant.UserQuery;
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("UserName", UserName);
    query.setParameter("UserPassword", UserPassword);
    List<Object[]> list = query.list();

    session.close();
    return list;
}
}
```

This is the HQL query;

```
from UserModel um inner join um.userRoleModel where um.UserName = :UserName and um.UserPassword = :UserPassword
```

Comment: if `user.getUserPassword()` would return a String the Exception would make sense - please post code from User with that method

Comment: I would check the signature of `user.getUserPassword()` one more time if I were you.

Comment: also: Line numbers (Exception / Code) might make sense to track this down

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace for a fast and correct answer.

Comment: Here is the complete stack trace;

Comment: can you provide your orm mapping? seems like you are storing data in db as `String`, and you are tying to access it as `char[]` and hibernate does not know how to convert them, and it tries to cast it, hence your exception

Comment: It looks like this isn't caused by the code shown, but by the query executed by `UserDAOImpl.login`; somewhere deep inside Hibernate a `char[]` is expected, but a `String` is offered.

Comment: Yeah i'm using varchar() for password, what should i use instead, is it char().

Comment: can you share com.humworld.ccs.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl.login(UserDAOImpl.java:29) and the related Query please?

Comment: What has to be done, can any one please tell;

Comment: can you provide `UserModel` class and mapping for that class, i think thats where is issue, in table you have string and you want to extract it as `char[]`. which version of hibernate you are using?

Comment: Thank you all, got the answer from jan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My theory on what happens:

You put a `String` into

```
 query.setParameter("UserPassword", UserPassword);
```

**BUT**

As you said, your `userPassword` property for your user Object is of type `char[]`

Now hibernate is a quite clever tool - it would recognize that object type for userPassword is `char[]` and then tries to set that into the generated query. But you passed a `String`.

Try this for once:

```
   query.setParameter("UserPassword", UserPassword.toCharArray());
```

in your login method.

Answer (score 0):

Try use 
`String userPassword = new StringBuilder()
.append(user.getUserPassword()).toString();`

Comment: This also throws the same exception.

Comment: it wont solve problem as problem is related to casting from `String` to `char[]`  not other way around

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String result=String.copyValueOf(charArray);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12151787)

Comment: @madhead: how is this not an answer?  It tries to directly address the error the OP reports.  Voting to keep this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast a String to a char (array, I'm guessing). I used a for loop.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  char[i] Letter = message1.charAt(i);
}
```

This was derived from my older code, but this should still convert the string `message1` to a char Array... Tell me if this would help :P

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the similar issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C
```

in the line

```
commons.validateException(String.valueOf(response.getBody().path("code")),
    String.valueOf(response.getBody().path("message"))
```

Adding `.toString()` resolved the issue. Below is the line of code.

```
commons.validateException(String.valueOf(response.getBody().path("code").toString()), 
    String.valueOf(response.getBody().path("message").toString())
```